# Labeling a thread by ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having issues trying to label a thread using the thread ID. My program gathers a list of IDs from Google spreadsheet and uses a for loop to iterate through the 2D array of IDs and afterward should label all of them "MyLabel". I get an exception saying Invalid argument at .addlabel(). This occurs when I use a specific ID or when I iterate through the array.

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var IDSheet = ss.getSheetByName("IDSheet");
 var IDdata = IDSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var label= "MyLabel";

 var IID= "179a9e43e23157f6";

 for(var o =0; o< IDdata.length;o++){
  GmailApp.getMessageById(IDdata[o]).getThread().addLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label));
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error?  Also have you already created the label with the name `MyLabel`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `IDdata` is an 2D-array, I believe that `IDdata[o]` in your loop is an array. You need just one element of this array. I don't know what the element it could be. If you meant first column then you can get this element this way `getMessageById(IDdata[o][0])`. If you mean second column it will be: `getMessageById(IDdata[o][1])` etc.

```js
var IDdata = [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
    ["a3", "b3", "c3"]
]

for (var o = 0; o < IDdata.length; o++) console.log(IDdata[o]);

for (var o = 0; o < IDdata.length; o++) console.log(IDdata[o][0]);
```

By the way, in modern Javascript you can use the more readable style for loops `for (var x of array)` that could help to avoid such errors:

```js
var IDdata = [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
    ["a3", "b3", "c3"]
]

for (var row of IDdata) console.log(row); // here you get the full rows

for (var row of IDdata) console.log(row[0]); // here you get one cell from the rows
```